# Command to run C++ with input from file

Tags: c++, command

**myC.cpp**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); // All inputs from 'input.txt' file

    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<(n+m)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The file `input.txt` may contains:

**Input.txt**

> 10 20

Command lines to build and run the code-

```
g++ myC.cpp -o myC
myC
```

It produces output `30` getting input from `input.txt` file.

**Now I am looking for a command which will similarly get input from a file, but want to avoid using freopen() inside the code.**

It might be something like this-

```
g++ myC.cpp -o myC  // To compile
myC -i input.txt    // To run with input
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what a compiler does...

Comment: If you delete the `freopen` line, you can invoke your command as `myC < input.txt`.  I don't think you actually want to compile `input.txt` into your program in some way.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `myC < input.txt`?

Comment: You are mixing two concepts, the compilation and the running of the code. The compiler does not know about executing your code

Comment: I didn't try to compile input.txt, I want input.txt as input of myC.cpp. I just want to avoid any syntax inside the code. Is it possible or not?

Comment: **Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pipe the input file to your program when invoking it from the command line. Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {

  int a, b;

  scanf( "%d", &a );
  scanf( "%d", &b );

  printf( "%d + %d = %d", a, b, ( a + b ) );

  return 0;
}
```

... say I compiled it as "test.exe", I would invoke it as follows to pipe the input text file.

```
./test.exe < input.txt
```

Comment: @DeadMG tagged as both C and C++

Comment: Flagged his comment for not reading the tags of the question and trolling.

Comment: Thank you. I exactly wanted it... :)

Answer (score 0):

While there is no single command that will do that (the compiler will not execute your code), for small tests I tend to run a single command line that will compile and execute if the build was correct:

> g++ -o myC myC.cpp && ./myC input.txt

Of course that requires changing your program so that the filename is taken as an argument, but that should be simple enough.

Comment: What is the function of input.txt here.

Comment: I imagine that you want to pass a file from which to read the contents. What is the use of `input.txt` in **your** code? If you want to do standard input, remove the argument and use shell redirections

Comment: But it does not work without freopen().

Comment: @MukkhoShukkhoManush: If you remove the `freopen` and substitute the call to be: `./myC < input.txt`, the shell will read `input.txt` and use its contents as standard input. The alternative I proposed is creating an `std::ifstream` initialized with the file passed as first argument, and then using that stream instead of `std::cin`. I have seen many programs that read/write to standard input and files, and this is the first time I recall `freopen` being used.